# Need comment on a Qemu source code line

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu

There is a definition for Translation Block in Qemu Source Code(cpu-exec.c)

[/qemu-0.14.0/cpu-exec.c](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download#Latest_Source_Code)

Line 127 says

static TranslationBlock *tb_find_slow(target_ulong pc,
                                      target_ulong cs_base,
                                      uint64_t flags)

what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a definition for a translation block, that's a function called `tb_find_slow()` which returns a pointer to a translation block. The translation block structure is defined in `exec-all.h`.

As to what they are, [this page](http://silviocesare.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/qemu-hacking/) has a succinct description:

> QEMU translates native instructions into ‘micro operations’ and builds them up as ‘translation blocks’.  When execution occurs, one of the first things that happen is that a lookup is made to find a translation block that has already been created.

In other words, it's sort of a just-in-time compiler.

There's a `tb_find_fast()` function which uses a hash based on a bit of CPU state (program counter, code selector and flags) which should be unique for each translation block. If that hash doesn't work (the resultant translation block has a different PC/CS/flags), then it reverts to the slow method, which is a sequential scan of the translation block list.

Comment: Is there any difference between basic block and translated block?

Comment: @user, basic blocks are simply bits of code without any transfer-of-control instructions (like `jmp` for example). It's basic blocks that become translated blocks, almost certainly to minimise complexity. If you can be certain a block follows certain rules, it can greatly simplify the work you need to do to translate it: "A translation unit contains just a single basic block (a block of x86 instructions terminated by a jump or by a virtual CPU state change which the translator cannot deduce statically)", from http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-tech.html.